# Are these two definitions the same ("syntactically")?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm stuck on how a problem is defined in a homework assignment. Does the below two definitions mean the same?
$$P(X_n = \pm 1) = \frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$P(X_n = -1) = P(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$$

My initial thought is that the first definition should be the same as,
$$P(X_n = -1) + P(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Any guidance on how to interpret the first definition correctly would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $P(X_n = -1) = P(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$.  In general, if a $\pm$ symbol appears, they mean that the statement holds for both the $+$ and the $-$.

Answer (score 1):

The first definition may mean $\mathcal{P}(X \in \{-1, 1\}) = \frac{1}{2}$ or $\mathcal{P}(X = 1) = \mathcal{P}(X = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$, depending on context.